# PHP Curl and XML Response - Updated

Tags: php, xml, curl

so after some great help, I've managed to get the script doing everything I need it to, but I need help with the next bit.

Please see my script below.
<?php

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.xxxxx.com/webAPI/api/stock',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<traderapi>
    <token>T1a5c3t9</token>
    <variant>Clearbank ltd</variant>
    <pon>X</pon>
</traderapi>',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Authorization: Bearer T1a5c3t9',
'Content-Type: application/xml'
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response
?>
```

I get the
[Picture of Chrome results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQJ1V.png)

The results that are displayed as this "210-AZBVTBC"

However in the code show this (as per the picture) "210-AZBVTBC4"

You can see I do a simple echo $response. How do I parse the information so I can show and manipulate how I show the individual tags. For example

echo ''.$response->Sku.'
';

Comment: a GET request with a POST body? i call bullshit, you're calling the API wrong. link to the api docs (while it's technically possible, it's pretty much always a bug, not intended usage.)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow :(

Comment: you're almost certainly not supposed to use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'` - instead you're probably supposed to set `CURLOPT_POST => 1` ... but to be 100% sure, we need the API documentation. where is the documentation for the API you're trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the result is a string not a file.
try using `simplexml_load_string`  instead of `simplexml_load_file`.

```
$Products = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

Comment: Thank you for this... However I get a new error now - AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in

Comment: @MatthewPayton you can probably ignore those strict XML warnings, try `$Products = @simplexml_load_string($response);`

Comment: I've done that now. I've updated the main question now with the new issue :) Thank you so far!

Comment: When you echo this, it parses as tags. Use inspect element to view the source

Comment: Hi Milad! thank you, so the source is down to the echo $response at the bottom of the script